# Request not returning

Tags: .net, azure, httpclient

I have an issue I have not been able to find any information about.

I have an api (hosted in azure) that have one endpoint that behaves very differently that the rest, basically that method hangs but all the rest work fine.

This method doesn't do anything much different that any of the others.

What happens is this:
1) An external (outside of azure) call to my endpoint.
2) I proccess that call (I log to insights and can see that).
3) I do a dependency call to another system (outside of azure). THis call is looged as OK in insights but execution is never return to my code. Before adding a Timeout I just hang, but since adding a timeout I time out.
4) Nothing is logged in insights after the dependency call and since the request is not finished the request itself is not logged.

The thing is, I use a RestHelper class that uses HttpClient and all my dependency calls use this same class. Every other call I make works fine. This specific call never returns execution to my code. I previously used WebRequest and that workes fine so there is nothing wrong with the external system I'm calling.

Since moving to HttpClient everything is async but I have not missed waiting on this particular call out.

Since I added the timeout I at least get an entry in my IIS logs now but they only say timeout.

I've run, trying to understand, this as far as I can and have no more avenues I know of to look into so I'm desperate for help.

```
public async Task<Response> ValidateUser(ValidateUser validateUser)
{
    var user = _userRepository.GetUser(validateUser.Id, false);
    if (user?.UserId == null)
    {
        throw new IntegrityException("Failed to get user.", Infrastructure.ErrorHandling.ErrorCodes.UserAlreadyValidated);
    }

    var account = GetAccountByUserId(user.UserId.Value, _accountRepository);
    validateUser.Id = account.AccountId;

    _logManager.Log("Validation -> Crm.");

    User validatedUser = null;

    try
    {
        validatedUser = await _userController.ValidateEmail(validateUser);   // <-- This call hangs
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logManager.Log(e.Message, SeverityLevel.Error);
        throw;
    }

    ...
}

public async Task<User> ValidateEmail(ValidateUser validateUser)
{
    var url = validateUser.EntityType == EntityType.Contact
        ? $"{_url}/{Contacts}/{validateUser.Token}"
        : $"{_url}/{Leads}/{validateUser.Token}";

    var user = new User
    {
        Token = validateUser.Token,
        InformationSource = InformationSource.ValidateEmail,
        Id = validateUser.Id
    };

    return await _restHelper.Put<User, User>(url, user); // <-- This call hangs
}


public class RestHelper : IRestHelper
{
    private static HttpClient _httpClient;

    public async Task<TModelOut> Put<TModelOut, TModelIn>(string url, TModelIn data, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        return await Operation<TModelOut, TModelIn>(url, HttpMethod.Put, data, headers);
    }

    private async Task<TModelOut> Operation<TModelOut, TModelIn>(string uri, HttpMethod verb, TModelIn data, IDictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        string body = null;
        var responseBody = string.Empty;
        HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode;

        if (typeof(TModelIn) == typeof(string))
        {
            body = (string) Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(string));
        }
        else
        {
            body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        }

        var content = new StringContent(body);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(Constants.ContentType);

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(verb, uri);
        headers?.ToList().ForEach(h =>
        {
            if (httpRequestMessage.Headers.Contains(h.Key))
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Remove(h.Key);
            }

            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(h.Key, h.Value);
        });

        httpRequestMessage.Content = content;

        response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage); // <-- This call hangs

        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;

        if (response?.Content != null)
        {
            responseBody = await response.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
            statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        }

        _logManager.LogRequest(uri, verb.ToString(), responseBody, statusCode, data);

        if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (typeof(TModelOut) == typeof(HttpResponseMessage))
            {
                return (TModelOut) Convert.ChangeType(response, typeof(TModelOut));
            }

            return await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<TModelOut>();
        }
    }

    ...

 }
```

Thankyou in advance for any help.

Comment: "Random" Question -  Are you using .Net CORE ?     It works on-prem but blows up only in Azure ?

Comment: The first method is in .Net Framework 4.6.1 and the last 2 is in .Net Standard 2.0. The RestHelper class is part of a nuget package used by several different azure app services and I'm working on refactoring a Third app service to use it as well.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your second question. Yes it workes fine when I run it locally, not involving azure. But not when uploading it to azure and running it through there.

Comment: I found in the .net Core code where this blows up - it scared me. I switched HttpClient stuff back to full framework. Have not checked after Core 2.1 came out.  Having some services in Full Framework and most in .net Core is starting to hurt me now that I am two years past working around the failure point you are encountering.  I will be watching your post to see if you ever figure a reliable way around this problem.  Its like Azure does an outer RunTask.False and there is no Async Context Tracking available for the Http Network calls.